# Xamarin Studio: GLSL syntax highlighting?

Tags: macos, xamarin, glsl

Besides writing it myself, how can I achieve GLSL syntax highlighting within *Xamarin Studio*?

*Xamarin* crashes every time I open a shader file, trying to parse the GLSL as C# I think. As an alternative I'm writing my shaders in *Sublime 2*, but switching programs is inconvenient.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were using this Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop Add-In. It still works with version 5.x if you mod the xml (see end of forum postings..).

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/monodevelop-syntax-highlighting-for-compute-shaders.164982/

[image]

### Note:

It is still available as a MonoDevelop AddIn (also Xamarin Studio):

Open your Add-On Manager:

[image]

Comment: @livin_amuk Thanks, fixed

Comment: The download only contains a .dll file. It shows up in the add-in manager but cannot be loaded due to "missing dependancies". Do I need to add the .xml file separately?

Comment: I just dropped the folder here and it worked /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/XamarinStudio-5.0/LocalInstall/Addins after a restart

Comment: @livin_amuk It is still available as a `AddIn`, I updated answer

Comment: Great, thanks again. Is it possible to apply the highlighting to other file extensions, for example .fs and .vs?

Comment: @livin_amuk You can add them via the `addin.xml` i.e. `<File pattern="*.fs" />`   https://github.com/jools-adams/monodevelop-unity-mimetypes/blob/master/MonoDevelop.UnityMimetypes.addin.xml Nothing fancy in the `Preferences` UI interface that I know about...

Comment: The contrary, everything fancy I don't know about! Importing the .xml file as a registered scheme blasts `"Could not be loaded. Object reference not set to instance of an object"`. ??

Comment: @livin_amuk Sorry, my bad, I'm used to writing AddIns not explaining them haha ... You would need to compile that dll (assembly), Grab the entire repo/project https://github.com/jools-adams/monodevelop-unity-mimetypes.git and add your additional file extensions, build it and install it (see the `install.sh` script also in that repo/project...

Comment: @livin_amuk AWESOME! have fun shading the mobile world